# How do I convert a string - 1year 6mon to an number 1.5?

Tags: python-3.x, string, pandas, integer, analytics

I have 2 columns where data is stored in the format '1yrs 6mon' format with multiple permutations of year and month value. How do I convert this to either 'total number of years' or 'total number of months' in python?

I did research on how to do this but could not find any suggestions

Expected output can look like the below
1yrs 6mon can be 1.5 years OR 18 months
0yrs 7mon can be 0.58 years OR 7 months

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pandas `str.extractall` and do a little preprocessing.

```
s = pd.Series(['1 yr 6 mon', '2 yr 5 mon'])
s

0    1 yr 6 mon
1    2 yr 5 mon
dtype: object
```

```
(s.str.extractall(r'(\d+)')[0]
  .unstack()
  .astype(int)
  .set_axis(['yr', 'mon'], axis=1, inplace=False)
  .eval('yr + mon / 12'))

0    1.500000
1    2.416667
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks this works smoothly. I was trying with pandas split but that would have become too many lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Another the way is using `findall`, `Transform` on Series and `apply` to `df`

```
In [98]: df
Out[98]:
           A           B
0   1yr 6mon    0yr 7mon
1  3yrs 4mon  2yrs 5mons
```

Define a custom function to use with `apply` on `df`. This function uses `findall` and Transform to return Series of years

```
def to_yrs(s):
    return s.str.findall(r'(\d+)').transform(lambda x: int(x[0]) + int(x[1])/12)

In [99]: df.apply(to_yrs, axis=1)
Out[99]:
          A         B
0  1.500000  0.583333
1  3.333333  2.416667
```